# Searching for a counterexample in periodic functions.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am looking for a function $f\in L_{\infty}[-\pi,\pi]$ which is $2\pi$ periodic and

$$||f||_{\infty}\leq 1$$

and

$$||\sum_{k=-N}^{N} \hat{f}(k) e^{ikx}||_{\infty} \gt 1$$

where $\hat{f}(k)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-ikx}dx$ is Fourier coefficient.

Does such a function exist?

Comment: how do you define $\hat{f}(k)$?

Comment: You might want to look at a continuous function whose fourier series diverges at a given point (for example at $0$). The existence of such a function can be shown and there are also specific examples of that.

Comment: @AlexR, do you have a specific reference in mind?

Comment: @Norbert, $\hat{f}(k)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-ikx}dx$.

Comment: Try $f=\chi_{[-a,a]}$. I'm sure I'll success for some $a$

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist Just google it, I'm very confident it will yield tons of examples (will be extremely oscillating)